# vertical-align: middle doesn't work for me?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't know why the div on the left doesn't align vertically to center.
here is the html:

```
<body >
    <div id="topH" class="vertCenter-flex">
        <div id="profileBox" class="bgc-green divmain centerItems" >
            <p>p1</p>
            <p>p2</p>
            <p>lala</p>
        </div>
        <div id="offers" class="bgc-blue divmain" ></div>
        <div id="news" class="bgc-purple divmain"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is the necessary css:

```css
.bgc-blue{
    background-color: #0066ff;
}
.bgc-white{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
.bgc-purple{
    background-color: purple;
}
.bgc-green{
    background-color: rgb(70, 223, 70);
}
.vertCenter-flex{
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.divmain{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display:  inline-block;
    vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
    height: 95%;
}
.centerItems{
    text-align: center;
}
#topH{
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
}
#offers{
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#profileBox{
    width: 30%;
    height: fit-content;
}
#news{
    width: 25%;
}
```

and this is the output. Again, i dont know what else can i do to center the left div vertically (#profileBox)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `align-items: center;` on the flex-container for that purpose.

```css
.bgc-blue {
  background-color: #0066ff;
}

.bgc-white {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.bgc-purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

.bgc-green {
  background-color: rgb(70, 223, 70);
}

.vertCenter-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.divmain {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
  height: 95%;
}

.centerItems {
  text-align: center;
}

#topH {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
}

#offers {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #fa0;
  height: 300px;
}

#profileBox {
  width: 30%;
  height: fit-content;
}

#news {
  width: 25%;
  background: #0fa;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="topH" class="vertCenter-flex">
    <div id="profileBox" class="bgc-green divmain centerItems">
      <p>p1</p>
      <p>p2</p>
      <p>lala</p>
    </div>
    <div id="offers" class="bgc-blue divmain">content</div>
    <div id="news" class="bgc-purple divmain">content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css

```
.vertCenter-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```